# The amazing lift.

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, algorithms

I would like to ask for a program to efficiently calculate how a lift should fetch the people who need it. Most of us use lifts (or elevators) but maybe it could be programmed to be faster! Or can it?

Firstly, let's consider that the lift has a limit. It can't take too many people or too much weight. So let's say it has a limit of 8 units.

Secondly, let's assume that there is only 1 lift in this building and it starts at level 1.

Thirdly, each request for a lift uses one unit.

Let's say it is a 10-level building. Each request is written as "b c", where the person is on level b and wants to go to level c. Getting some requests through RANDOM.org, I get:

3  9
10 1
10 3
9  2
8  7

One method would be for the lift to start at level 1, go to level 10 and back down.

But this method would not work in real life because there are times it will get to more than 8 units and the lift will break and more importantly, who would want to go down but end up going up to the top floor?

Take note that for the case above, the lift can take both 10-1 and 10-3 together.

---

The problem:
If the requests are:
10  7
8   7
2   1
2   1
9   2
3   6
9   7
6   1
9   8
10  8
what is the shortest amount of time for all the passengers' requests to be fulfilled?
Each request is 1 unit and the lift can only take up to 8 units at any time.
The lift starts at level 1.
The requests are all needed at the same time and they can be finished in any order.
The lift can only go in the direction the passenger wants it to go to.
Calculate the shortest amount of floors the lift has to travel. (i.e. from level 1 to level 3 is 2 floors.)

---

p.s. this is not exactly true. More people would go to level 1 at the start of the day while most people would go back to their house in the evening.

---

Edit: there are also many factors that can affect. The timing of the requests may be different, the number of people going in together may vary and there may be more than one lift, which as @Joffan has stated. All these factors will change the problem very badly. Also, you can choose how you want to solve it (by computer or brute force).

Edit 2: A program or alogorithm will be appreciated as they will be able to solve other combinations as well.

Comment: Do you want us to solve this by hand or are we expected to write some code to brute force through it?

Comment: Douglas Adams (Hitchhiker's Guide etc) suggested a scenario where lifts were given the ability to know the future, thereby knowing where they were going to be needed.

Comment: You do need some data to model accurately the behaviour of lift travellers at different times of the day. I expect there will be different algorithms that need to be operated on at different times of the day.

Comment: Most lift requests are simply "up" or "down". Only when you are in the lift can you request a particular floor. Your algorithm will have to deal with that kind of partial information.

Comment: Things get a lot more interesting when you have 2 or 3 (or more) lifts.

Comment: @tomi I agree. Lift requests will not tell the destination. However, it will be very hard to present it on a post. Not only that, we also never know when a request is made. This problem will ignore all these, but I may continue with more variations of this problem after it is finished.